# This site can’t provide a secure connection but works in incognito mode

Tags: google-chrome

Trying to run webapp (localhost) but I'm receiving this error..,

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
> localhost sent an invalid response.
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

**The website is not using https**

But I tried with https as well

[image]

Both works in incognito mode!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not using https?
This might be your browser protecting you from a http site. Can you try to select more and continue to risky connection/unsafe connection, etc.

**EDIT:** Check out http://neverssl.com/ as it explains how you can accomplish this.

Comment: yes.. http://neverssl.com/ works!  My browser is not protecting me from http connections.

Comment: @ridermansb now you can try removing all ssl and see if that works.

Comment: how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Open a new browser tab in chrome, go to `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`

Scroll down to "Delete domain security policies" and enter the root domain that's causing you issues. For example, `localhost`

Then, click the Delete button.